# IOS Mobile Safari Horizontal Scrolling div

Tags: html, ios, css

I am basically at a dead end here and am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I have a simple Div that contains multiple divs, lined up horizontally. I have this Div set to 'overflow-x' so I can scroll it horizontally above the other items below it ( This is used for a navigation element )

When I 'touch scroll' to scroll the content tot he right or left it does not scroll ( Android works just fine ) I have tried everything I can think of but nothing seems to work. What is strange about this is I have a 'trunk' menu that slides out from the left and a top level Div shows itself, its just a fixed position div with a background transparency. Anyhow the strange part comes when I have that 'shown' the damn thing will scroll properly!

Now for the sake of time I was thinking well hell if I can get that to work I can just show a stupid div, set a touch event and go on my way, but the touch event seems to have a double click lag or something, just didn't work right so I ditched that. I started to back track up the dom tree to see if there was a css conflict but nothing would work. I have tried turning off just about every CSS element and still wont work. What is strange is that I have a 'main' container div all of my 'pages' load in this div ( single page app ) when I place it outside this div it will work as well but there is no style on this main container, so I have no idea why the scrolling Div would work outside that Div but not inside the div ( maybe I'm missing something with IOS? [ I should add the content gets loaded dynamically via JS ] )

Like I said its a whole bunch of weird going on and I'm not sure why this would be happening and it only seems to happen on IOS ( IOS 9 testing device )

Any advice as to what might be happening would be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?